# Android Studio Project Structure (v.s. Eclipse Project Structure)

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm trying to learn android development and I am initially confused by the different project structures between Eclipse and Android Studio. This makes it difficult to follow tutorials designed for Eclipse. Could anyone let me know why these differences exist? Should they exist?

For instance, if I were to locate the R.java file in the two different IDEs, the paths would look like this:

**Eclipse:** app\gen\com.example.app\R.java

**Android Studio:** app\build\source\r\debug\com.example.app\R.java

Why are these paths different? Why is my R.java located in a  debug folder in Android Studio? This lead to some errors early on, and if anyone has any insight into these differences I would appreciate them.

Comment: I tried to post images in this question, but I need at least 10 reputation. I will edit the post to include the images once I qualify.

Comment: Why don't you use Eclipse so you only tackle the Android specific problems and not the IDE stuff(especially as Android Studio is in  *early access preview*)?

Comment: Agreed. Unless you have at least a year of Android development experience, IMHO you should not be messing with Android Studio until it leaves "early access preview" mode.

Comment: I would add that you can use IntelliJ IDEA instead, as it is very stable. Additionally, once Android Studio is more stable, the move to it will be very easy as they are the same IDE (with AS providing enhanced Android integration only).

Comment: I've had 3 years of experience in Android dev using Eclipse and I seriously find it difficult using A.Studio. I wish someone gave a straight answer since it's time people moved; I've moved. I don't want to work on hunches during development.

Comment: Do not focus on those auto-generated and IDE specified files (gen/, bin/, target/, build/ and etc). The only files that need go into SCM is src/, res/, asset/, libs/, AndroidManifest.xml and project.properties, these are IDE independent part of your project and required by any modern IDE for reconstructing your project.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

## The mystery: Android Studio's Project Structure and Build System

I don't know if this is because of the Gradle Build System (I'd wager it is), but I'll tell you what I've understood so far.

**Update 4:** 2014/09/11 Added **Cheat Sheet** for `BuildTypes`, `Flavors` and `Variants`(I finally feel confident to write this :D)
**Update 3:** 2014/09/11 Updated the comparison workspaces and projects to be precise
**Update 2:** 2014/04/17 Added more detail to AS project structure
**Update 1:** 2013/07/29 Added IntelliJ Project Structure

The IntelliJ's Project structure (shown at the end) is for IntelliJ with the android plugin. The Android Studio, however, has a project structure divided like so:

### Structure: Projects and Modules

**module** in *Android Studio* is like a **project** in *Eclipse*

**project** in *Android Studio* is like a **workspace** in *Eclipse* (to be precise, a workspace with interdependent projects)

From [the documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Structure+of+IntelliJ+IDEA+Project) (Android Studio is based on Intellij IDEA) :

> Whatever you do in IntelliJ IDEA, you do that in the context of a
>   project. A project is an organizational unit that represents a
>   complete software solution.
>
> Your finished product may be decomposed into a series of discrete,
>   isolated modules, but it's a project definition that brings them
>   together and ties them into a greater whole.

For Android, it means one project per app, and one module per library and per test app.

There are multiple issues if you try to build multiple apps within the same project. It's possible, but if you try (like I did), you will see that almost everything is designed to work with a single app per project.

For example, there is an option to "rebuild the project", which makes no sense with multiple apps, many other project settings would be useless, and the built-in VCS system isn't great when you have multiple repositories.

### Structure: Folder Structure

[image: Android Studio Project Structure]

#### Top Level Folders

#### 1. Main Project

This would be entire **project context** (**Eclipse Land:** Like your workspace but limited to what's relevant to your project). Ex: `HelloWorldProject` if the name of the application you gave was `HelloWorld`

#### 2. .idea

This where project specific metadata is stored by Android Studio (AS). (**Eclipse Land:** `project.properties` file)

#### 3. Project Module

This is the actual project. ex: `HelloWorld` if your application name you gave was HelloWorld

#### 4. gradle

This is where the gradle build system's jar wrapper i.e. this jar is how AS communicates with gradle installed in Windows (the OS in my case).

#### 5. External Libraries

This is not actually a folder but a place where Referenced Libraries (**Eclipse Land:** Referenced Libraries) are shown. Here's where the Targeted Platform is shown etc.

[**Side note:** This where many of us in Eclipse Land used to delete the referenced libraries and Fix Project Properties to fix reference errors, remember?]

### Project Folder in Detail

This is number #3 in the above list. Has the following sub dirs

#### 1. build

This has all the complete output of the `make` process i.e. classes.dex, compiled classes and resources, etc.

In the Android Studio GUI, only a few folders are shown. The important part is that **your R.java is found here** under **`build/source/<flavor>/r/<build type(optional)>/<package>/R.java`**

#### 2. libs

This is the standard libs folder that you see in **eclipse land** too

#### 3. src

Here, you only see the `java` and `res` folder which correspond to the `src` folder and `res` folder in **Eclipse Land**. This is much welcomed simplification IMHO.

### Note on Modules:

Modules are like **Eclipse Land** projects. Here the idea is that you have one application project (Module #3 in the list above) and several library projects(as separate Modules under the global project folder (#1 in the above list)) which the application project depends on. How these library projects can be re-used in other applications, I still haven't found out.

[**Side note:** The whole re-organization has some benefits like simplifications in src folder, but so many complications. The complications are mainly due **VERY VERY** thin documentation on this new project layout.]

## The New Build System

[User Guide for the new Build System](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)

### Explanation of flavors and buildTypes, etc - What is the hullabaloo about?

#### CheatSheet for flavors and buildTypes

**BuildType:** `debug` and `release` are `buildTypes` available by default on all projects. They are for building/compiling the **SAME CODE** to generate different APKs. For example on `release` APKs you would want to run proguard(for obfuscation), sign it with your key (as against the debug key), run optimizations (maybe via proguard or other tools), use slightly different `packageNames` (we use `com.company.product` for `release` and `com.company.product.debug` for `debug`), etc. We also use a debug flag (`BuildConfig.DEBUG`) to turn off logging to logcat (since it makes the app slow) on `release` builds. This makes for a faster `debug` build during development but also an optimized `release` build to put on play store.

**Product Flavor:** There are no default flavors available (or to be precise, the default flavor is blank/nameless). `Flavors` could be **free version** or **paid version** where they have **DIFFERENT CODE**. They share the same `Main` Code but different versions(or no versions) of a few source code files or resources.

**BuildVariant:** A `buildVariant` is what a generated APK actually corresponds to. They are named like so (in order) **`Product Flavor` + `Build Type` = `Build Variant`**.
**Example 1:** if you have `free` and `paid` as two flavors. The build variants you would get are:
    Free - debug
    Free - release
    Paid - debug
    Paid - release
So that is 4 possible APK configurations. A few configurations may not make sense in a particular project, but they **are** available.

**Example 2:** (for new projects/ no flavors) You have 2 `buildVariants` or APKs available, since the default flavor is nameless/blank:
    debug
    release

## Compare this with [Intellij's Project Structure](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Developing_applications_for_Android_in_IntelliJ_IDEA#Creating_a_New_Project) if that helps:

[image: Intellij Project Structure Snapshot]

**The .idea (1)** folder contains a number of subfolders, mainly with internal IntelliJ IDEA information.

**The src (2)** folder contains the MyActivity.java **(3) file source code** that implements the functionality of your application. The file belongs to the com.example package.

**The res (4)** folder contains various visual resources.

**The layout/main.xml file (5)** defines the appearance of the application constituted of resources of various types.

**The values folder (6)** is intended for storing .xml files that describe resources of various types. Presently, the folder contains a strings.xml file with String resources definitions. As you will see from the Adding a Color section, the layout folder can also contain, for example, a descriptor of colors.

**The drawable folder (7)** contains images.

**The gen (8) folder** contains the **R.java (9)** file that links the visual resources and the Java source code. As you will see from the sections below, IntelliJ IDEA supports tight integration between static resources and R.java. As soon as any resources are added or removed, the corresponding classes and class fields in R.java are automatically generated or removed accordingly. The R.java file also belongs to the com.example package.

Comment: Thank you very much for comparing the Eclipse and Android Studio project structures! And yes the documentation on this project structure and how it might be used in everyday development is non-existent.

Comment: "3. src Here, you only see the java and res folder..." To be more precise, `java` and `res` are under `src/main`.

Comment: Here is some documentation about the Android Studio folder structure: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html

Answer (score 32):

> Android Studio: app\build\source\r\debug\com.example.app\R.java
>
> Why are these paths different? Why is my R.java located in a debug folder in Android Studio? This lead to some errors early on, and if anyone has any insight into these differences I would appreciate them.

Simply put, Android Studio is configured to build a debug [**Build Type**](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types) on your system.

Eclipse/ADT is designed to support a single build at a time (from what I can tell). One of the primary goals of the new build system ([from the user guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Goals-of-the-new-Build-System)):

```
Make it easy to create several variants of an application, 
either for multi-apk distribution or for different flavors of an application
```

So where as Eclipse/ADT could generate one `R.java` file, Android Studio supports multiple. The generated `R.java` is located in the `debug` folder because by default the new build system supports `debug` and `release` build types off the bat. If you changed your build variant (button, lower left hand corner of AS) to release AS will generate `R.java` in the `release` directory.

This might not mean anything for simple projects, but the support of [**Build Variants**](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants) means a drastic simplification of the build process for many developers, including the project I'm working on.

Our project supports 4 flavors with 2 build types (debug and release), to support a total of 8 different APK combinations. And each of those combinations have slightly different configurations, so this build system really worked out for us. My android studio is installed on a different machine, but if memory serves my correctly the `R.java` file exists in `build/source/<flavor>/r/<build type>/package/R.java`. When our CI server builds the APK files it uses each of these `R.java` files to generate separate packages.

Answer (score 0):

> Google [Discontinue the support](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html) for the Android Developer Tools
>   (ADT) in Eclipse is ending, per our announcement. You should migrate
>   your app development projects to Android Studio as soon as possible.
>   For more information on transitioning to Android Studio, see Migrating
>   to Android Studio.

**So best for Android development tool for [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html) only for all future support of [Android M](http://developer.android.com/index.html) ---**

Comment: Eclipse for Android Developers - https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-android-developers-includes-incubating-components/neonr

Answer (score -2):

For android Studio 3.0.1 and selected all features:

- Android O latest
- Android Auto
- Android things
- Android wear
- Android TV
- C++ support
- Kotlin support

The structure in version 3.0.1 does not look at all like all other answers.

Recent structure is as displayed in 2018, Android Studio 3.0.1 01/2018.

Newbie kinda found something resembling to usable in feature sub-folder:

[image]

Update your Android Studio 3.0.1 01_2018:

[image]

ToolTip:

[image]