# Too early to use Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm just getting into some Android development, and came across Android Studio. I know it's pretty early days, but it seems relatively stable and I'm very familiar with JetBrains other tools (which it is based on), so it seemed a good fit.

However I'm finding that every tutorial or article I can find on Android development explains things in terms of Eclipse.

To me it seems that Android Studio will be the way forward, and so I'm relunctant to learn Eclipse only to have to migrate everything later.

So what are the technical limitations of each choice...

If I stay with Android Studio, what major differences will I need to be aware of when trying to make sense of tutorials designed for Eclipse.

...OR...

If I switch to Eclipse, how difficult will it be to move across to Android Studio later?

Comment: I tried in Eclipse and I found it easy.. ;)

Comment: I don't think it should matter much since the source is the same.

Comment: Before using Android Studio profesionally you should wait for version 1.0 or maybe 1.1. For now it's better to try it personnally at home . That's what i think ^^

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849078/what-android-ide-is-better-android-studio-or-eclipse

Comment: Indeed, I use eclipse at work, and Android Studio at home :) Easy to migrate from one to other.

Comment: Android Studio can have lots of bugs. Heared some negative feedback from guys that tried it. Never tried it myself though. If you need your project fast and stable - go for Eclipse. If you feel you have enough time to migrate to Eclipse if Android Studio's bugs will block your job you can go for it.

Comment: I have been using IntelliJ IDEA and the Android plugin for years. Android Studio is just a rebranded IDEA 13 EAP. EAP means there are bugs. So if you want to be on the safe side use IntelliJ IDEA 12. Switch to Android Studio or IDEA 13 when IDEA 13 is released. If you know Android programming it is easy to switch now. If you depend on tutorials to be for the IDE you are using, you should use Eclipse for now.

Comment: IMO, get at least 3 months of android app development under your belt before going for AS. From what I've heard it sounds more stable lately, but you're not going to have a lot of support for the hurdles you run into in the early stages while you're still learning everything.