# what i choose? adt(eclipse) or android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, adt, software-distribution

I have already used eclipse. but android developer recommend to android studio.
which ide is best and future development?

any one can suggest me.

Comment: Did you try to investigate any pros and cons for both ide before doing the post here?

Comment: Answer to your question seems to be based on opinion so the answer will be varied from person to person. For me, i used eclipse as i have used it before and there is lot of issue support available online.

Comment: Its not a proper question . By the way choose Android Studio

Comment: I just switched to android Studio and must admit, that I like it more then eclipse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849078/which-android-ide-is-better-android-studio-or-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google does not support Eclipse ADT anymore. you have to ready about Android Studio.

I think migration Eclipse to Android Studio is not really hard.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommended you use Android Studio, AS more faster and more intelligent. And it just release a stable version V1.0.2. But first, you may need to spend a lot of time to learn how to use it.You can download the software from here: [Android Studio Download Link](http://tools.android.com/download/studio). And I suggest you learn the Gradle build system first: [Gradle build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)