# Android Studio VS ADT Bundle

Tags: android

I got my laptop reformatted so I need to start all over again to continue my android app. So basically I installed the Android Studio I dunno what happened but I THOUGHT it was the ADT Bundle. So here I am now with the AS. My question is, is it possible to continue my codings here at AS? Does it affect things? I made my project at Eclipse Juno. TIA :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Android IDE is better - Android Studio or Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849078/which-android-ide-is-better-android-studio-or-eclipse)

Comment: @2Dee That question is off-topic.  If you think this one is also off topic, then vote that way and don't suggest a meaningless duplicate.