# Eclipse vs Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I'M Currently Using **Eclipse** For Android  Development And I have *an uncompleted Project also*.Is it better moving to **Android Studio**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which Android IDE is better - Android Studio or Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849078/which-android-ide-is-better-android-studio-or-eclipse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can move to Android Studio. Also after completing the project you can move to Studio. It is a step by step process to move a Eclipse project to Android Studio project.

Follow the link below:

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Answer (score -1):

I used both the IDE and in my case Android Studio is more efficient for android development. And another thing is if you have a incomplete project then no issue just import the project to android studio, you may need to change some small things then you are ready to go.

Hope this helps you :)