# Close module in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

in eclipse there is simple option to close or open project. How can I do it in android studio to close and open module without import it and delete each time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849078/which-android-ide-is-better-android-studio-or-eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no notion of opening and closing a module in Android Studio. There should be no need to do it.

You seem to be treating an Android Studio project as being the equivalent of an Eclipse workspace, and IMHO that is not a valid comparison.

Comment: ok lets say I have a module and I want it to use as an .aar library. So I delete module and use aar format. But when I want to change something in that library, do I have to import that library as a module? Or could I keep the module in my project? If it's possible I disable it; and whenever I need to make a change, I can get a new aar format and disable module again. Is it possible or maybe any other solutions?

Comment: @MiloRambaldi Have the library in a separate project. You can have multiple IDE windows open at once. Have the project with the library publish to a local Maven repo that the app pulls the artifact from.

Comment: thanks I'll try that. I have an another question. Is there any building performance difference between using module and aar? Both usage compiled in gradle's dependencies.Does this make any difference?

Comment: @MiloRambaldi I have not attempted any performance analysis comparing these, sorry