# Unable to identify source of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException BaseDexClassLoader

Tags: java, android

I have got lot of crash report in my android app from users as I see in the developer console. The stack trace that I see is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:

  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2884)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)

  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1565)

  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)

  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)

  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5728)

  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:789)

  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:469)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:2879)
```

There is no reference to my app's package name. I am using Eclipse for my development. Is it something related to multidex. Do I need to switch to Android Studio to solve this. I am unable to understand the basic reason behind the stack trace so that I can look for a solution for it.

Note: I have google play services, IAP and OneSignal Sdk added to my app

Comment: Any more input you can give on the issue? Have you been able to reproduce the error? How does it occur? etc.

Comment: You should be using android studio.

Comment: You should have some version info for us..

Comment: I have this error in increased number after I included a third party library.

Comment: may be this will help you dude https://github.com/casidiablo/multidex#whats-it-for-again

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I would personally say that Android Studio has the edge over the
>   two.Android studio is becoming more popular day by day among the
>   android development community and also the open source community. **[Android Studio or Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849078/which-android-ide-is-better-android-studio-or-eclipse)**

Read **[Migrate to Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html)** .

> Migrating your projects to Android Studio requires adapting to a new
>   project structure, build system, and IDE functionality. If you are
>   migrating an Android project from Eclipse, Android Studio provides an
>   import tool so you can quickly move your existing code into Android
>   Studio projects and Gradle-based build files.

**Logcat Throws**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
```

**[BaseDexClassLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/BaseDexClassLoader.html)** Base class for common functionality between various **`dex-based ClassLoader`** implementations.

> In order to configure your app project to use a MultiDex
>   configuration, you must make the following modifications, depending on
>   the minimum Android version that your app supports.

set [**`multiDexEnabled true`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) to your **<kbd>build.gradle</kbd>** `module-level` file , as shown below:

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion //
    buildToolsVersion //

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion //
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' 
}
```

You can check **[DexIndexOverflowException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33430306/3395198)** .

Comment: Will try this today and let you know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are using pro guard and need to exclude some classes.
Make sure you have excluded any library used in your project.