# Can Android Studio convert ant build script to gradle build script?

Tags: android, ant, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Hi I want to convert ant script to gradle.Is there a tool for automatic conversion?

I was trying Android Studio and found out that if you import a project with ant build it asks you that shall it covert it to gradle.Even when you click yes,it generates a gradle script containing

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {`
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Does anyone know where I can find the converted gradle script,or any other method to do so?

Comment: I don't think such a tool exists.

Comment: @vishine Any solution that you came up with in the last 10 months?

Comment: @JoshPinter: did *you* come up with any solution?

Comment: @user1587329 Ha. No. I had to do it manually.

Answer (score 3):

#### Concerning your question

> Does anyone know where I can find the converted gradle script,or any other method to do so?

Gradle creates two `build.gradle` files: one at the project level, one in the project directory. `app/src`. The second might contain the directives you have been looking for.

You might want to have a look at a [more detailed description of the Android Studio files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17684051/1587329).

#### If you came here to convert a generic ant to a gradle script

This works out-of-the-box as of AndroidStudio 1.3.