# Is there a way to generate the R.java file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, r.java-file

I have a saved Android project from long time ago and now I must to work on it.

I've created a New Project in Android Studio and I've imported all the Java and XML files inside it but the `R.java` file is missing.

I guess that it didn't save the original. 
Can I recover it somehow or generate it?

Comment: When the project is built the R file is generated. I'd suggest a Build -> Rebuild Project

Comment: I did your you've suggested but it doesn't generate the R file. Are you sure that it must be generated? Or I must perform this task near after I'd created the project?

Comment: Yes, it's generated. If you look in project/app/build/generated/source/r/ it should be listed in there.

Comment: It isn't and I don't know why. In the location you've mentioned is only a folder 'debug' which is also empty: http://i.imgur.com/2iRnNBK.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`R.java` is quite different in Android Studio than it is in Eclipse. Since you say this is an old project, I'm assuming that it was originally from Eclipse. In Eclipse, `R.java` is included in the source tree. However, in Android Studio, it is hidden away. From [another Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17684051/2581872):

> #### 1. build
>
> This has all the complete output of the `make` process i.e. classes.dex, compiled classes and resources, etc.
>
> In the Android Studio GUI, only a few folders are shown. The important
>   part is that **your R.java is found here** under
>   **`build/source/<flavor>/r/<build type(optional)>/<package>/R.java`**

You shouldn't need to manually interact with `R.java` at all. It can be re-generated from the source code. Thus, it is likely that you won't have any problems -- `R.java` will be auto-generated and all will be well. If it isn't, try a rebuild of the project.

Comment: Nope, the original was from Android Studio too, and it isn't that old... about 7-8 months. I've rebuilt the project and nothing appeared..

Comment: Does the project build, @migea? If so, you don't need to worry about it -- it's there.

Comment: I don't but in the original project it was so, and there are calls from it in the project's classses as it can be seen here: http://i.imgur.com/sTldGAC.png

Comment: @migea That's normal, but you don't need to import `my_package_name.R`. It resolves automatically -- if you remove the import statement, it should fix your build errors & cause `R.java` to be generated.

Comment: Well, I've commented the imported R files and after that I've rebuilt the project. It still doesn't work. This is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/InBHkLb.png

Comment: I've succeeded finally. Now it has suggested me to import that files and it works fine. Thanks for your support

Comment: Its not getting generated It says could not find symbol 'r', I rebuilt the project, cleaned the project, Restarted the eclipse ,Cleared the cached...Still no Luck :(