# how to add already existing android project to android studio and build it

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an Android project. I imported it to to Android studio. I recognized all my java files and created the module . But i do not see my Android Manifest file anywhere in the android studio. Neither the build.gradle files are generated. 
Please help me how to properly add already existing android project to android studio and build it.

Comment: How do you import your project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Project Structure (v.s. Eclipse Project Structure)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431838/android-studio-project-structure-v-s-eclipse-project-structure)

Comment: @Bala Raja File->New -> Import Project . it prompted for project location . i choose the location and it got imported

Comment: @Devendra Singh in my case after importing there is only the source code , no build.gradle file , no android manifest file , no res folder is there . I wonder whether the import is proper or not.

Comment: Then create new project and paste code

Comment: Be patient. Sometimes you need to wait til gradle tasks finish. Did you try to display your projet tree in Project mode (default is Android mode) ?

Answer (score 0):

[Manifest location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWspl.png)

Are you sure your manifest is not there, because the location has changed according to your android studio version.. 
Look at the first line of the picture i uploaded (in the "Manifests" section)