# How to change file hierarchy in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't know how but the android studio changed the file hierarchy of my project...

see the image below.

[image: This was the file hierarchy by now to changed to the 2nd picture]

This type was proper the image that is above this line .

The image that is below this line was automatically created by the android studio.

[image: This type is very hard to use..]

How to change back to the older file hierarchy type??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In left upper corner of *Android Studio* you need to change the project view to **Android**. Your current project view is **Project**.

[image: See this image]

Answer (score 1):

[Android Studio Project Structure (v.s. Eclipse Project Structure)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431838/android-studio-project-structure-v-s-eclipse-project-structure)

This link will help you to understand the folder structure of android studio.
And all the new folder created in your project after compile it in android studio is all because of folder structure of android studio and dont worry it will never harm your project.